# How do I make a div hidden by default using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to toggle visibility of a div area:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
 </script>
```

To toggle it, I am using onclick="toggle_visibility('id_of_element_to_toggle');"

The part that I don't like is that this makes it visible by default when the page loads.  How can I make it hidden by default until it is toggled to be visible?  I'd like to do this in the same javascript block if possible.  The simpler the better.

How can I toggle the visibility of 2 divs at once?  To make them switch.

Comment: You're looking for CSS, not JS to have it hidden by default...

Comment: Use CSS, `display: none`, no need for Javascript here

Comment: so if I just do style="display:none" in the div tag that should do it?

Comment: could you kindly accept an answer?

Answer (score 9):

You need to call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

toggle_visibility('id_of_element_to_toggle');

function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
 </script>
```

You could add some CSS too:

```
#id_of_element_to_toggle{display:none;}
```

Performance will be faster with CSS.

Comment: +1 this actually answers the OP's question along with providing the better css alternative

Comment: looks like all the answers answer the question, just with different levels of detail.

Answer (score 7):

In cases such as this I hide the div using css, either inline or in the stylesheet, so that it is hidden by default.

```
<div style="display:none;">
```

Or, you could load the div without content, then populate it via your javascript with e.innerHTML="some content" or ajax?

Answer (score 6):

since you're using CSS to toggle it, you should use CSS to set its initial state:
`display:none` either inline in the `style` attribute or ideally in a global stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple option is to set this in the CSS, then it will truly be set as hidden from the moment that the style is applied by the browser, before your Javascript is executed:

```
div.item_name { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
    <div id="foo" style="display:none">toggle visibility.</div>


    </body>
    </html>
```